# Saturacion del bufer

Tags: c++, array

acabo de empezar de programar el programa.. puede que la funcion y demas no este terminado correctamente pero el problema que me estoy encontrando en este  momento es uno que ya se me ha repetido varias veces intentando resolver otros ejercicios y hoy decidi ponerle fin jajaj...

> Gravedad Código    Descripción Proyecto    Archivo Línea   Estado suprimido. Error C4789   se producirá una saturación del búfer 'numBinario' con un tamaño de 120 bytes; se escribirán 4 bytes empezando en el desplazamiento 120

¿**Que significa** este error y sobretodo, **como lo evito y como lo soluciono**? se que tiene que ver con los arrays y sus tamaños pero no se me ocurre solucion.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;
int decimalBinario(int, int[]);

int main()
{
    
    int i = 0, numDecimal=0, numBinario[30];

    printf("Ingrese un numero para pasar a binario: ");
    scanf("%d", &numDecimal);

    numBinario[30] = decimalBinario(numDecimal,numBinario);

    printf("El numero %d pasado a binario es:  %d", numDecimal, numBinario);


    return 0;

}


int decimalBinario(int numDecimal, int arrayBinario[]) {

    int i = 0;

    while (numDecimal > 2) {

        arrayBinario[i] = numDecimal % 2;

        numDecimal = numDecimal / 2;

        i++;


    }

    return arrayBinario[30];

}
```

Comment: Puede que se deba a que estás escribiendo en una posición fuera del arreglo (`arrayBinario[30]`). En el `while` deberías verificar que `i` tampoco se salga del rango. ¿Y no crees que sería mejor idea usar elementos con menor capacidad para almacenar cada bit del número? Por ejemplo podrías usar `bool` o `char`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declaras un array con 30 elementos

```
int arrayBinario[30];
```

A continuación intentas escribir en la posición **31**, es decir, fuera del array. Recuerda que los índices empiezan en 0:

```
arrayBinario[30] = decimalBinario(numDecimal,numBinario);
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ <<--- AQUI
```

Pero es que ademas, en la función `decimalBinario` devueles también la posición 31 del array:

```
return arrayBinario[30];
```

Realmente te puedes ahorrar tanto la asignación como el return. La función, en principio, ya está recibiendo una referencia al array `numBinario`.

Por otro lado, un array no se puede imprimir con `%d`:

```
printf("El numero %d pasado a binario es:  %d", numDecimal, numBinario);
                                           ~~               ~~~~~~~~~~
```

Para imprimir un array tienes que recorrer, de forma manual, todas sus posiciones.

```
void decimalBinario(int, int[]);

int main()
{
    
    int i = 0, numDecimal=0, numBinario[30];

    printf("Ingrese un numero para pasar a binario: ");
    scanf("%d", &numDecimal);

    decimalBinario(numDecimal,numBinario);

    printf("El numero %d pasado a binario es: ", numDecimal);
    for (int digito : numDecimal) printf("%d", digito);

    return 0;

}


int decimalBinario(int numDecimal, int arrayBinario[]) {

    int i = 0;

    while (numDecimal > 2) {

        arrayBinario[i] = numDecimal % 2;

        numDecimal = numDecimal / 2;

        i++;


    }
}
```

Y, para terminar, o programas en C o lo haces en C++. Son lenguajes que, aun teniendo una base común muy grande, no son 100% compatibles, y de hecho cada uno tiene características que el otro no soporta. En tu caso, dado que incluyes  la librería `<iostream>`, asumo que programas en C++ ... pues bien, si programas en C++, aprovecha sus características:

- usa `cin` y `cout` en vez de `printf`, `scanf` y compañía
- No importes librerías básicas de C `<*.h>`. En su lugar tienes una versión que empieza por c `<c*>`. `<stdlib.h>` -> `<cstdlib>`